# LSTM Text Generation Applied on a Time Series with Keras

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on time series prediction. [LSTM for Regression with Time Steps subsection](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) in the link gets me going pretty well. However, I want to predict into the further future, not only one-step ahead (i.e. predict every step into the future up to 30th step -- so a sequence generation), and text generation on LSTM networks sounds like the thing I am looking for.

To give an example for my ultimate goal, think of the famous Shakespeare text generators. I am trying to either feed all of Shakespeare's works and get a new Shakespeare "play," or complete an unfinished Shakespeare play (because he died without completing this particular work). Is there a way to translate this *feature* of **sequence generation** to time series, if so, can you point me towards any resources or examples.

Thank you.